# Targum Onkelos on זה קרבן פלוני בן פלוני

Tags: targumin, artscroll, parshat-nasso

At the end of Naso, there is a difference in the Stone chumash's Targum Onkelos (edit: it's the same in the Dirshu chumash) between Nachshon and the other nesiim.  For Nachshon, it says:

> דין קֻרְבָּנָא דנחשון בר עמינדב

while for Netanel and the rest, it says:

> דין קֻרבַּן נתנאל בר צוער

Bar Ilan Responsa and Mechon Mamre both have the same for all of them, which is a mix of those versions:

> דין קרבנא דפלוני בר פלוני

Where does the Artscroll version come from?  Why should there be a difference between Nachshon and the others?

EDIT:

This is what I originally had for Nachshon, I'm sure I saw this somewhere but can't find it now, the version in every Stone chumash I checked (large and small, editions ranging 1996-2006) is as above.  As @DoubleAA points out in the comments to my answer, this is inconsistent with Artscroll's source for the Targum.  Hidden to avoid confusion with the confirmed versions.

> דא קָרְבָּנָא דנחשון בר עמינדב

Comment: I find that the Stone Targum often has mistakes. My guess is that this is one of them. (But your question stands regardless.)

Comment: I would recommend [contacting Artscroll](https://artscroll.com/ContactUs.aspx) to see what they have to say about this. They may even be able to identify what version[s] of the Targum they used in compiling the Stone Edition.

Comment: @IsaacMoses done

Comment: Artscrol Yaffa chimash has דין קרבן for all. But my תרגום המוגה והמדוייק has דן קרבנא, with דן written chassar.

Comment: Note that Sperber's critical edition appears to agree with Bar Ilan/Mechon Mamre. http://cal1.cn.huc.edu/get_a_chapter.php?file=51004&sub=07&cset=H&clen=5

Answer (score 2):

> Thank you for contacting us with your inquiry.
>
> The text of our Targum Onkelos is from Chumash Toras Elokim (Vilna, 1874) which includes R' Wolf Heidenheim’s text of the Targum; that text is based on manuscripts and is considered מדוייק.
>
> We appreciate the opportunity to clarify this.

Cover page image from a later email from Artscroll.  It's not exactly the one @DoubleAA links to in the comments, pagination is also different, but the text of the Targum looks the same from a few pages they also included in the email.
[image: cover page]

I'm not marking this answer as correct because it doesn't explain the underlying reasons why Nachshon is different than the others.  In a followup email, they told me that they don't know any reason for the difference.

Maybe I'll try asking Dirshu when I get a chance.

Comment: Did you ask them why their newer Chumashim no longer have that version?

Comment: @user6591 no, I asked them before you mentioned that, I'll send a reply.  Do you have any idea which version newer printings of the Stone have?

Comment: +1 but it is a partial answer as to where they got it from. I don't know what the new ones have.

Comment: "R' Wolf Heidenheim’s text of the Targum" What is that? Heidenheim died before 1874 and his Chumash Meor Einayim didn't have Targum in it...

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm not familiar with him, but [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf_Heidenheim) does mention the Chumash Toras Elokim and says that it has the Targum.  It's under "Works", not under "His Pentateuch editions".  Apparently it was published (or republished) in 1874.

Comment: @Heshy It says he started it and never got past the middle of Genesis.

Comment: Here's the 1874 Vilna Toras Elokim Chumash and as you can see http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40108&st=&pgnum=76 the Targum doesn't match Artscroll's. Please send them this link and say common guys. (It has דין קרבן for every Nasi but the first where it has דין קרבנא)

Comment: @DoubleAA interesting, I sent them an email summarizing the comments here (although I linked to this question in my original email, it would be easier for everyone if they would just come here and answer it).  Either way, my original question about why Nachshon is different stands (and is not an Artscroll mistake, although it still could be an older one).

Comment: The Vilna editions are quite problematic in my experience. Their girsaot often stray from other versions due to the censors heavy hand. I doubt that they would have followed the Rawa"h in Vilna regardless, as he was often smeared as a reform-leaning maskil, due to his work of Yitzchok von Satanov (the Pachad Yitzchok).

Answer (score 1):

I just checked my mikros gedolos from mechon hamaor and the Torah temimah. Both have the odd דין קורבנא דנחשון followed by דין קורבן אליאב and similar for all the rest.

So here's a couple of theories.

1. This first passuk was mistakenly 'fixed' based on the Targum Yerushalmi, which has the reading  דין קורבנא דיסדר וכו׳. There is a continued longer phrase used there which wouldn't have been so easy to jam in, so it wasn't.  As for why nobody stuck the variation found in that targum into the other nissiim, well, that because they're not printed out being that what we have printed as targum yerushalmi is sporadic.

The reason I would call this 'fix' a mistake is because targum pseudo Yonason in passuk 17 reads דין סדר קורבנא די יקרב etc. as does passuk 23. The other pesukim follow with וגו׳, so we can't be sure but let's assume the pattern would continue. These two targumim usually follow a more similar pattern when compared to Onkelus.

2. This next theory is just a grasp at a straw without really understating why it would be true. We find one variation in Nachshon's pesukim where the Torah begins by saying וקרבנו, with an extra וי׳ו. This is addressed in the mefarshim (see Ibn Ezra Rashbam Rabeinu Bachaye and others). So perhaps, for some reason, the refocusing of the pesukim with that וי׳ו will end up with a קורבנא דפלוני. But I can't give a guess as to why.

Comment: I was wondering about וקרבנו also, I just don't know enough Aramaic grammar to have any idea why that would make a difference.

Comment: Agreed. I checked Shaarei Aharon. He's my go to on insights into Targum. He didn't mention anything.

Comment: @Heshy I checked Nesina LaGer frrom Rav Nosson Adler found here http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39717&st=&pgnum=52 he doesn't say anything. The Targum printed in that seffer has the same interesting wording, but I don't know if it is the same version he had himself.